# Pentaho Server 8.2 fails to resolve file path in transformation

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I am using PDI 8.2 CE and Penatho BI Server 8.2CE. Transformation works fine locally where the .ktrs and files are saved in local folders, using ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory} to map a text file that is used in the ktr. However once this is uploaded to the Penatho BI Server (saving the text file in the same folder as the ktr) and try to run it the ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory} is resolved as "file:///C:/public/ErrorHandlingSample/UnitTestData_MultiType.txt" instead of the relative repository directory !!!

I don't know what change can make it working again? If anyone hit the same issue please help...

Thanks heaps..

Some logs below,

```sh
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - An error occurred while creating field mapping
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - Could not read from "file:///C:/public/ErrorHandlingSample/UnitTestData_MultiType.txt" because it is not a file.
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - 
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - Could not read from "file:///C:/public/ErrorHandlingSample/UnitTestData_MultiType.txt" because it is not a file.
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - 
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.readFieldNamesFromFile(CsvInput.java:463)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.createFieldMapping(CsvInput.java:427)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.openNextFile(CsvInput.java:332)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.processRow(CsvInput.java:135)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFoundException: Could not read from "file:///C:/public/ErrorHandlingSample/UnitTestData_MultiType.txt" because it is not a file.
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1123)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.DefaultFileContent.getInputStream(DefaultFileContent.java:349)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getInputStream(KettleVFS.java:263)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.readFieldNamesFromFile(CsvInput.java:443)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   ... 5 more
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\public\ErrorHandlingSample\UnitTestData_MultiType.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.local.LocalFile.doGetInputStream(LocalFile.java:215)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1119)
2019/08/13 13:02:29 - Scenario 1 Input Data 2.0 -   ... 8 more
```

Comment: i had same error. the file was opened in word or any other software. may be that's the one reason in your case.

Comment: not in my case because the file is saved in repository. Where you able to achieve this with Pentaho Server?

Comment: Do you need the pentaho-sever or you just need to execute your transformation? Are you able to use carter or kitchen/pan with pentaho? These tools, works perfectly as PDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pentaho repository is not intended to be a store of any file type other than Pentaho reports, and Pentaho transformations/jobs. The ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory} variable will only work to reference things like text files while in the Windows/Mac/Linux file systems. While inside the Pentaho Server, that variable is used to reference other transformations or jobs, it won't work to reference things like text files. You should create a direct path to the text file that the Pentaho Server JVM can access.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's is the case. Do you know of any alternate ways to overcome this apart from saving the files in a separate location?

Comment: If the data in the text file is very small, you could just use a Data Grid step in a transformation and manually input the data. If the data is large in the text file, you should probably reconsider if the use case makes sense. It might make more sense to use something like a database to store that data and have a transformation that connects to that database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we will have to look into finding out how big the files are..